# Automator / Applescript : how to get original from folder alias

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm trying to create a context menu shortcut to open a file/folder in VS Code from the original item or its alias

So far I was able to create an Automator Service, which:

- receives selected: files or folders
- in: any application run
- shell script:

`open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args "$*"`

How can I change it to accept also aliases?

Answer (score 2):

Symbolic links should be OK, but Finder aliases usually don't work, since most shell utilities see them as small data files and don't know how to interpret them.  One solution would be to add a **Run AppleScript** action to look for aliases in the input and use the original item instead, for example:

- Service receives selected *files or folders* in *any application*
- **Run AppleScript**:

  ```
  on run {input, parameters}
    set output to {} -- this will be a list of the output items
    tell application "Finder" to repeat with anItem in the input
      if anItem's kind is "Alias" then
        set the end of output to POSIX path of (original item of anItem as alias)
      else
        set the end of output to POSIX path of anItem
      end if
    end repeat
    return output
  end run
  ```
- **Run Shell Script**, etc